Failed update from 22.04.4 LTS to 24.04.1 LTS - missing fail safe installation
There was a power loss in the middle of the upgrade.
Now the whole system is no more working, wan't boot up, can't continue with the upgrade in a terminal and can't unroll the installation -> leaving the whole system useless.
What can I do to recover?

I’d reinstall then restore your data from backup.

That's the only way.

However, I've tried to upgrade Ubuntu Studio 22.04 on a VirtualBox machine. It did the Job, but crashed immediatly after reboot ... not really a stable way to upgrade.

Managed it, to start it in the console.
$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found.
Why ???

net-tools are missing, any networking is not available. Is that the sense of an upgrade, to let the users stay without network? How to install anything without network on Linux?

Sounds really like a joke: $ ifconfig
Der Befehl 'ifconfig' wurde nicht gefunden, kann aber installiert werden mit:
sudo apt install net-tools

This is the worst ever upgrade I had in the last 40 years. If I'm really enforced to reinstall the whole system again, this was the last time I've ever used this OS.

Voting to close: Newer information buried among comments, the OP claims upgrade failure is NOT due to power loss after all.

This question is similar to: Lost power during upgrade, how do I recover?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu) are vulnerable to severe damage if a release-upgrade is interrupted. There is no "rollback" nor "failsafe". (Exception: Ubuntu Core's snap-only design offers rollback)
That's why there are warnings when you start the process. And that's why support volunteers strongly recommend regular backups.
If your system is unbootable after an aborted release-upgrade, then reinstall Ubuntu and restore your data from backups.
If you don't have backups, use a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment to rescue your data onto some other media.

Well if so, I think the better way is to install a complete new system, then transfer the data. The upgrade seems not to work, even on another system.
I've tried on a VirtualBox machine and on a Laptop too.
Both crashed on reboot after upgrade.

Crash-after-upgrade seems completely different from your original question, which was about an external interruption (poweroff). This answer is about your original question. If you can reliably reproduce crash-after-upgrade, then please file a bug report with step-by-step instructions for a developer to reproduce in their test environment. Bug discussion is off-topic in AskUbuntu, and reporting bugs does not occur here.

The crash was on ANOTHER system. The problem is the same: The upgrade is not reliable.

Now I've seen, the crash was not the problem, but the upgrade itself. I've tried on several systems with Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu and Ubuntu Studio. Each failed on each system. The system were: My desktop PC, a hp Notebook and Virtual Box. First I've installed a bare 22.04 then tried to upgrade to 24.04 without any success.

I've managed it the following way:

First brought a virtual machine to run with the newest version (24.04).

Because networking was not installed properly, I've configured it manually according to https://linux.fernandocejas.com/docs/how-to/switch-from-network-manager-to-systemd-networkd

Then I handled to access my fixed disk and copied all new files from the VM to the defect installation.

Reboot and voila - finished (What a mess ... took me weeks now.)



Well the upgrade broke the settings of the system. My opinion is now: never do an upgrade. Choose a new installation and copy the settings from the old system. Any upgrade is not really working.
